# How can I retrieve data a week after from the oldest day in the database?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, date-arithmetic

I want to retrieve data a week after from the oldest day in the database. I know i can get oldest one using

```
MIN(datefield)
```

I want to do something like that

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE {{Week before oldest}} >= datefield AND datefield <= {{oldest}}
```

How can i get {{Week after oldest}} and {{oldest}} values?

Comment: Do you mean you want to retrieve the 1st week of data (7 days) from the table?  It is not possible to have 'Week before oldest' in my opinion.  The oldest date can not get any lower.

Comment: Its mistake, i mean week after the oldest

Comment: So you want to get oldest date + 7 days for starting date through next 7 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a subquery:

```
select *
from mytable t
where datefield < (select min(datefield) + interval 1 week from mytable)
```

This selects the first week of data. If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can also use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, min(datefield) over() as min_datefield
    from mytable t
) t
where datefield < min_datefield + interval 1 week
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you to skip 1st week of data and retrieve second week of data.

```
SET @begdate=0;SELECT MIN(datefield) + INTERVAL 1 WEEK FROM mytable INTO @begdate;
SET @enddate=0;SELECT MIN(datefield) + INTERVAL 2 WEEK FROM mytable INTO @enddate;
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE datefield BETWEEN @begdate and @enddate;
```

Good luck, welcome to StackOverflow.  Happy Holidays.